# Optimizing webservice response message

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, apache-axis

I'm facing a performance issue with my web-service.

**The context**

I'm coding a game on Android that consumes a web service. It 's a multiplayer game so there are many connections done to the web service.

My Rest web service is provided by an Axis2 instance on a Tomcat server.

**The problem**

All is working fine, except that the amount of data is huge because of the verbosity of XML.
I tried to optimize the exchange by never resending a data that the client already have.
I use gzip compression.
I think that jSon is not a solution because, it will light the response message but not as I would.

So my questions, what should I do to maximum  light the response size? What are the best practices?
Is it possible to send only a serialized object without using jSon or xml to avoid verbosity?

Comment: ah, the price of success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your reponses xD
I think that I have to send serialized objects in a custom format but Axis2 only deals with xml stuff (Jax-WS).

So I'll try another Rest server like Jersey which deals with custom format (Jax-RS). 
What do you think about that?